# Using mogrify to decrease image size

Tags: linux, mogrify, image-quality

I'm trying to use mogrify to decrease the quality of the image to ultimately decrease the image size but rather than decreasing it, the image size is increasing. I'm using the following command:

```
mogrify -quality 20%  1.png
```

The image size is going from 2.5 mb to 4 mb, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PNG is a lossless format, so changing "quality" settings should do nothing at all with respect to the "image".
The [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) documentation confirms this - "quality", when applied to a PNG, indicates which row filters to apply: a value ranging from `0` to `6`.

Since the input `20` is *invalid* for a PNG file, it must have been silently replaced with a default value; presumably `0`, which indicates *no* row filtering at all. (If you really want to know if this is the case, you could use a tool such as `pngcheck` on your before and after images.)

As to your target: it is unclear whether you want to decrease the *physical* image size in pixels, or the *file size* on disk, or (possibly) both. For the first, you can use `-resize`. For the second, try a PNG-recompressing tool such as `pngcrush`. For both, use the first method and then the second.

Another option may be to lower the number of color components, for example, from 24-bit RGB to indexed color. Finally, you can always convert the image type from PNG to JPEG, after which you *can* experiment with the "quality" parameter.